# Configuration Error in IIS 7 for Virtual Directory ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, windows-server-2008, virtual-directory

This could be an issue with many things, but I'm trying to narrow down the source of the issue in my IIS setup or web.config configuration.  That's where I need your help.  I will explain my setup below.  Normally I create web sites in IIS 7, and not virtual directories, but I have a bunch of shared JavaScript frameworks in my root directory (unminified right now), and I have a bunch of applications sharing those files.

My theory is that I do not have configuration for the web site itself.  The path of the web site is the folder above the virtual directory path.  Something tells me I need this, but I don't remember what it needs to look like.

Thoughts?

Note, this setup works just fine in Windows XP virtual directory setup.  But I get this error on both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008.

**Here is the website error:**

[image]

**Error in text (for searching):**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Descriptionn: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.  Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

<compilation debug=true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

**Website URL:**

```
http://localhost/app/index.aspx
```

**Changed these 3 settings in my app pool (of the site in which the virtual directory resides in):**

[image]

**Disabled 'Anonymous Authentication' and Enabled 'Windows Authentication':**

[image]

**web.config file in virtual directory folder (sub folder of web site):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <configSections>
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
        <!-- Local Machine -->
        <add name="DATABASE" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASE-DEV;User ID=sa;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    </connectionStrings>

    <!--<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="DataAccessQuickStart">
    <providerMappings>
      <add databaseType="Devart.Data.Oracle.EnterpriseLibrary.OracleDatabase,Devart.Data.Oracle.EnterpriseLibrary" name="OracleX" />
    </providerMappings>
  </dataConfiguration>-->
    <!--<location path="." allowOverride="true">
  </location>-->
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users = "?" />
        </authorization>

        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>

        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>

        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>

        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet" />
                <add name="HttpPost" />
            </protocols>
        </webServices>

        <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false" />


    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>

    <!--<identity impersonate="true" />-->

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you configured the virtual directory as 'application' in IIS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to configure the virtual directory as 'application' in IIS

Comment: It's funny how this question earned a "Notable Question" badge, but nobody up-votes the question or answer.  I up-voted your answer and that was it.  The answer is so simple, but hundreds of thousands of people must need to know this answer.  :-)